# How to store resources into a blazor WASM application like to a Windows exe file

Tags: blazor, webassembly

When writing Windows applications I can store resources of any kind into the exe file.
How can I do the same for a blazor wasm application? E.g. I would like to store strings into a resource file which should be saved into the wasm assembly by the compiler. In my C# classes I would load the strings and use them. I do not use the strings for  internationalization. They contain base 64 coded binary data. I don't want to load the resources by special url requests and expose them to the internet.

How can I achieve that? If not possible, what are the alternatives?

Comment: It's a client application.  Any data you have in there is already exposed to the internet.  A proper answer to your question would need to be better informed of your purpose.

Comment: "I don't want to load the resources by special url requests and expose them to the internet."  All your WASM executables and associated files are exposed on the Internet.  They can be downloaded, picked over and read at will.